# Session working accurately on localhost but not working on live server

Tags: javascript, php, session, mysqli

I have a admin panel for login. I have created a login page with php, 
 html, java script. I used session to pass user to next page. This working perfectly on my localhost. But on live server i am getting problem, its showing me "loged in successfully" popup and redirecting back to login page. When i print session on localhost its showing me session value but on live server its empty. I have searched so many answers and tried same but still it's not working. Please help and thank you for your time and consideration.

My live server is **Apache HTTP Server Version 2.2**

My connection file **db.php** is

```
<?php

/*Default time zone ,to be able to send mail */
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

//connect database
$con = mysqli_connect ("localhost","rootuser","password","testdbname"); //host, username, password, database name

        //database connect error
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        {   
        echo "Failed to connect to MySql: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
        }
?>
```

**login.php** file is

```
<?php 
session_start();
include("includes/db.php");

if(isset($_SESSION['mysesiuid']))
{
  header('Location: index.php?alreadyin');
  //echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php?alreadyin')</script>";
}

else
{

?>          

<script src="assets/js/validate/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
//login script 
$(document).ready(function() {

    var mazalagna_login_email1 = 1;
    var mazalagna_login_email2 = 1;
    var mazalagna_login_email3 = 1;
    var mazalagna_login_password = 1;

    $("#main_login_submit").click(function(){


        //password
        if($("#mazalagna_pass").val() == ''){
            $("#mazalagna_pass").css("border","1px solid red");
            $("#mazalagna_password_error").show();
            mazalagna_login_password = 1;
        }else{

                if($("#mazalagna_pass").val().length < 6){
                    $("#mazalagna_pass").css("border","1px solid red");
                    $("#mazalagna_password_length_error_longform").show();
                    $("#mazalagna_password_error").hide();
                    mazalagna_login_password = 1;
                }else{
                    $("#mazalagna_pass").css("border","1px solid green");
                    $("#mazalagna_password_length_error_longform").hide();
                    $("#mazalagna_password_error").hide();
                    mazalagna_login_password = 0;
                }
        }



        //email
         var pattern = /^([a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+(\.[a-z\d!#$%&'*+\-\/=?^_`{|}~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]+)*|"((([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))*(([ \t]*\r\n)?[ \t]+)?")@(([a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\d\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.)+([a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]|[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF][a-z\d\-._~\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]*[a-z\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])\.?$/i;
        var validateMazalagnaEmail =  pattern.test($("#mazalagna_email").val());

        if($("#mazalagna_email").val() == ''){
            $("#mazalagna_email").css("border","1px solid red");
            $("#mazalagna_email_error").show();
            mazalagna_login_email1 = 1;
        }else{
            $("#mazalagna_email").css("border","1px solid green");
            $("#mazalagna_email_error").hide();
            mazalagna_login_email1 = 0;
        }

        if(!validateMazalagnaEmail){
            $("#mazalagna_email").css("border","1px solid red");
            $("#mazalagna_email_error").show();
            mazalagna_login_email2 = 1;
        }else{
            $("#mazalagna_email").css("border","1px solid green");
            $("#mazalagna_email_error").hide();
            mazalagna_login_email2 = 0;
        }

        if(validateMazalagnaEmail){
            $.ajax({   
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,
                    url: "php/ajax_email_exist.php",
                    data: { email: $("#mazalagna_email").val()},

                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        if(data != 1){
                            $("#mazalagna_email").css("border","1px solid green");
                            $("#mazalagna_exist_email_error").hide();
                            mazalagna_login_email3 = 0;
                        }else{
                            $("#mazalagna_email").css("border","1px solid red");
                            $("#mazalagna_exist_email_error").show();
                            mazalagna_login_email3 = 1;
                        }

                        if(mazalagna_login_email1 == 0 && mazalagna_login_email2 == 0 && mazalagna_login_email3 == 0 && mazalagna_login_password == 0 ){

                    $.ajax({   
                            type: "POST",
                            cache: false,
                            url: "main_login.php",
                            data: { 
                                    username1: $("#mazalagna_email").val(),
                                    password1: $("#mazalagna_pass").val()
                            },

                            success: function (data)
                            {
                                alert(data);
                                //alert("Welcome! You have loged in successfully!");
                                window.location.replace("index.php");
                            }
                    });
            }
                    }
            });
        }   

        //edit value    
        $(".regval").click(function(){
                var id = "#"+$(this).attr("id");
                var errorId = "#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_error";
                $(id).css("border","1px solid #a39e9e");
                $(errorId).hide();
        }); 


    });
});
</script>

                        <strong>   Enter Details To Login </strong>  

                            <!--    <form role="form" action="" method="post">  -->

                                     <div class="form-group input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-tag"  ></i></span>
                                        <input type="text" id="mazalagna_email" name="mazalagna_email" class="form-control regval" placeholder="Your Username" required />
                                     </div>

                                     <div id="mazalagna_email_error" style="display:none; margin-top:-12px; margin-bottom:12px; text-align:center; color:red; font-size:12px;">Please enter valid Email</div>
                                     <div id="mazalagna_exist_email_error" style="display:none; margin-top:-12px; margin-bottom:12px; text-align:center; color:red; font-size:12px;">Your email id is not registered.</div>

                                     <div class="form-group input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock"  ></i></span>
                                            <input type="password" id="mazalagna_pass" name="mazalagna_pass" class="form-control regval"  placeholder="Your Password" required />
                                     </div>

                                     <div id="mazalagna_password_error" style="display:none; margin-top:-12px; margin-bottom:12px; text-align:center; color:red; font-size:12px;">Please enter your password</div>
                                     <div id="mazalagna_password_length_error_longform" style="display:none; margin-top:-12px; margin-bottom:12px; text-align:center; color:red; font-size:12px;">Enter min 6 character password</div>


                                     <button type="submit" id="main_login_submit" name="main_login_submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Login Now</button>
                                    <hr />
                                <!--    </form>  -->

<?php } // top else close here ?>
```

My **main_login.php** file is

```
<?php
//connect database
 session_start();
 require_once 'includes/db.php';
 global $con;

  $user_email = trim($_POST['username1']);
  $user_password = trim($_POST['password1']);

  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, md5($user_password));

    $res = $con->query("SELECT * FROM useradmins WHERE email='$user_email' AND password='$password'");
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();

      $uid = $row['admin_id'];
      $name = $row['name'];
      $useremail = $row['email'];
      $pass = $row['password'];

    if($useremail==$user_email && $pass==$password){

            $_SESSION['mysesi']=$name;
            $_SESSION['mysesiuid']=$useremail;

            echo "Loged in successfully.";  

    //update status and login time

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
        $date_email = date('F j, Y h:i A');  
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $user = $_SESSION['mysesiuid'];
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $httpref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        $httpagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        $update_last_login="UPDATE useradmins SET admin_status='ONLINE',active_ip_address='$ip',admin_last_login='$date' WHERE admin_id='$user'";

        $update_last_login = mysqli_query($con, $update_last_login);

    }
    else{
            echo "Unable to login.";
    }

?>
```

**index.php** file is

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once 'includes/db.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['mysesiuid']))
{
  header('Location: login.php');
  exit;
}
else
{

?>


<h1>hi success</h1> 


<?php   }   ?>   <!-- top else statement close here -->
```

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing. PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: @sherry123 - Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);`  after `session_start();` and tell us what you see... (wouldn't hurt to add it to all php files, at least while you are still developing your application---I wouldn't recommend keeping it on when you go live/to production though)

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for your suggestions. I will make changes for my password. So it will be more secure.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: @Rushikumar thanks for your reply. I have added `error_reporting(E_ALL);` after `session_start();`. Its showing me blank screen.

Comment: You dont seem to be redirecting to the I am logged in page when you get a successfull login or am I missing something

Comment: @sherry123 out of curiosity, what are the logs saying? Also, it's worth cross checking/comparing your php.ini file that you have locally to that of the server's --- do a quick diff...

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am using javascript for that in **login.php** file.

Comment: @Rushikumar thanks ... I have to check servers php.ini file and log file.